# Spring - Hibernate will show DEBUG, won't show sql

Tags: spring, hibernate, log4j, slf4j

I'm using Spring 3.x and Hibernate 4.x on my web project.

The problem is it will show DEBUG messages but sql statements that I need for debugging.

Here are my settings.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    </bean>

    <!-- Data Source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.tmax.tibero.jdbc.TbDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="****"></property>
        <property name="user" value="****"></property>
        <property name="password" value="****"></property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>50</value></property>
    </bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
         <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

         <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the config below. I hope this may help those who are having the same trouble. I moved any hibernate related config properties into hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```